# Delete character in an XML file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

I am working with Ruby, and I want to delete all the `\` characters from my XML file.

Here is my XML file:

```
<w:numId w:val=\"2\"/></w:numPr></w:pPr><w:bookmarkStart w:id=\"0\" w:name=\"__DdeLink__0_226207805\"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id=\"0\"/><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:t>Serve high quality food</w:t></w:r></w:p>, <w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=\"style17\"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val=\"0\"/><w:numId w:val=\"2\"/></w:numPr></w:pPr><w:bookmarkStart w:id=\"0\" w:name=\"__DdeLink__0_226207805\"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id=\"0\"/>
```

Comment: What you are displaying looks like the output of a `puts` using IRB. Escaped double-quotes like that would be invalid XML in a file. What do you see when you open the file in an editor?

Comment: Yes you are right, my XML is invalid and when i opened it in an editor the backslashes does still exist

Comment: How are you getting the XML? If it's being sent to you, then contact whoever sends it and tell them they're doing it wrong and to fix it. If you're scraping it then you might not be doing it right. This question sounds like an XY question, where you ask about Y but should ask about X, but without more information we can't help you beyond trying to clean up after the mess occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for you answers, here is what i dit and it worked as i wanted:

```
 text = ''
      File.open("#{temp_dir}/plan_report_template/word/document.xml").each { |line|

       text << line

      }


      open("#{temp_dir}/plan_report_template/word/document.xml", "w") { |file| file.write(text.gsub('\"', '"')) }
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to show us what you did, unless it's to be your selected answer to solve the problem which you figured out by yourself.

Comment: Tin Man i showed you what i did so you can have an idea of the solution that worked for me

Comment: Is this to be your selected answer? Otherwise, don't do that.

Comment: Yes it is my proper answer

Answer (score 1):

There's actually no backslash character (`\`) in your file. The backslash in your example simply escapes the following double-quote and prevents it terminating the string and thereby resulting in a syntax error due to an unterminated double-quote.

What you see when you print that string in IRB is actually not the backslash as is, but the backslash in combination with the following double-quote as an indication that the double-quote is escaped. The idea is kind of hard to grasp when you encounter it the first time. Have a look at "[Escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences)".

Saying it short and sweet, there is no backslash in your file so you can't remove it.

Let me explain with an example:

```
> text = "This is sample text for escape character\""
#=> "This is sample text for escape character\""
```

Is equivalent to:

```
> text = 'This is sample text for escape character"'
#=> "This is sample text for escape character\""
```

To remove the backslash (`\`) , just remove `"`

```
 > text.tr!('"', '')
 #=> "This is sample text for escape character"
```

I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response, lets say i have a text file with the same content as above and i want to remove all the backslashes, what is the ruby expression to do so?

Comment: This work great great when using a single line, but I have a full text which is full of backslashes and i do the folowing expression(when using a single line it work but here doesn't) File.open("#{temp_dir}/plan_report_template/word/document.xml").each { |line|

       line.gsub('"/\\/"', '')

      }

Comment: @mourad: This link should help you understand about escape characters: http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex10.html. You are right though, if you did have any '\/ (backslash characters in your string, your code would remove them, line by line.